# Destination file already exists and could not be deleted when upload

Tags: java, file, multipart

My web app is made on Spring MVC. I have a method where the user can upload PDFs 
.
 The I am sending the file as mutlipart file to the server. Every time the user uploads.

All what I want is to send the files as attachments in that email.
My code

```
private File prepareAttachment(final MultipartFile mFile) {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + mFile.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            if(file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }
            mFile.transferTo(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfE) {
            file.delete();
            LOG.error(" file was not found.", fnfE);
        } catch (IOException ioE) {
            file.delete();
            LOG.error("file has failed to upload.", ioE);
        }
        return file;
    }
```

calling the method to prepare the attachment:

```
MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            @Override
            public void prepare(final MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

                File file = prepareAttachment(form.getFile());
                File file2 = prepareAttachment(form.getFile2());
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

message.addAttachment(form.getFile().getOriginalFilename(), file);
message.addAttachment(form.getFile2().getOriginalFilename(), file2);
```

Getting exception:

```
    2017-08-28 15:10:59,549 ERROR com.menards.requestForms.business.service.EmailService - file has failed to upload.
java.io.IOException: Destination file [C:\opt\tcserver\main\temp] already exists and could not be deleted
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.transferTo(CommonsMultipartFile.java:160) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.menards.requestForms.business.service.EmailService.prepareAttachment(EmailService.java:552) ~[classes/:?]
```

this will work perfectly if I comment out adding the second file :(

```
message.addAttachment(form.getFile2().getOriginalFilename(), file2);
```

any advise?

Comment: Stop doing `file.delete()` when it doesn't exist. Have you checked that `file.canRead()`? What does it output?

Comment: I added the "file.delete()" as trying to fix the issue. it will throw the same error without it.

Comment: I don't know why people giving the vote down, when I really see this is an issue and not an easy one!!

Comment: I see 1 vote up :) anyways you didn't answer my question: what's the output of `file.canRead()`?

Comment: I'm testing that right now. :) and thank you!

Comment: It's giving me false ...

Comment: Probably the user running the app doesn't have permission to delete the file.  What user creates the file and what user deletes it?

Comment: Make sure original file name is not empty. My guess is that you're just getting your temp directory as file. Can't delete it as it is a non-empty directory, can't transfer to it as it still exists.

Comment: It's on my local, trying to upload the file. not sure if I have to do anything for user permission.

Comment: I can see the files uploaded to the temp directory, but it's failing to attach them to the email.

Comment: The method [File.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) doesn't throw an exception on error, it returns `false`. Try using [`Files.delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-)`(file.toPath())` instead.

Comment: can I delete the exist files in that directory before I add the new files?

Comment: hmm, I got the " file.canRead()" as true now with different trace. 
                                                  
         Java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\opt\tcserver\main\temp
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_60]

Comment: That means that `file` is a directory and you're trying to delete it. You can only delete a directoy (through the File API) when it is empty.

Comment: That was my first issue! thank you very much for helping me! you and @Andrew hepled me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't let your users determine the path of a file that you're creating on your server - it introduces a lot of security vulnerabilities. In this case, they may be attempting to create a temp file that has the same as *some other file* in your temp directory, potentially one that has nothing to do with your current application. `File.createTempFile` ensures that it creates a file with a unique name on each invocation.

It's also good practice to clean up temp files as soon as you're finished with them, so you don't have to worry about maintaining state on your server between method calls. This can sometimes create code that's a bit *busy* with catch/finally blocks, but it's worth it to avoid waking up at 3 AM to a hard disk that's full of garbage temp files.

I'd implement this roughly as:

```
private File prepareAttachment(final MultipartFile mFile) throws IOException {
    File tmp = null;
    try {
        tmp = File.createTempFile("upload", ".tmp");
        mFile.transferTo(tmp);
        return tmp;
    } catch (IOException ioE) {
        if (tmp != null) {
            tmp.delete();
        }
        LOG.error("file has failed to upload.", ioE);
        throw ioE;
    }
}

MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
    @Override
    public void prepare(final MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
        File file1 = null;
        File file2 = null;
        try {
            file1 = prepareAttachment(form.getFile());
            file2 = prepareAttachment(form.getFile2());
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

            message.addAttachment(form.getFile().getOriginalFilename(), file1);
            message.addAttachment(form.getFile2().getOriginalFilename(), file2);
            // do your other stuff
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // some sort of error-handling, probably returning a message with an error status
        } finally {
            if (file1 != null) {
                file1.delete();
            }
            if (file2 != null) {
                file2.delete();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you!  @pedromss helps me to figure the first issue and you helped me to solve the  clean up! thanks for both of you!